# How to choose the quality of a YouTube video?

Tags: ios, objective-c, youtube-api

How can I download and play back a YouTube video with different quality values such as "High," "Low," and "Normal"?

Answer (score 0):

You can use PSYouTubeExtractor.h class It can get youtube mp4 video url and than downloading and viewing is not a problem

Here is my example "[Project](https://github.com/comonitos/youtube_video)"

Also Check this Github Projects [here](https://github.com/freemanrepo/YouTuber) or [here](https://github.com/laeroah/YoutubeDownloader)

Comment: Sorry But I Cant Get It What You Provide

Answer (score 0):

Using YouTube's [iOS Player Helper class](https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper/) (YTPlayerView), you can load a video by a suggested quality value;

ViewController.m

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet YTPlayerView *playerView;

// ...

[self.playerView loadVideoById:@"zN-GGeNPQEg" startSeconds:0.0f suggestedQuality:kYTPlaybackQualitySmall];
```

Quality options in YTPlayerView.h:

```
/** These enums represent the resolution of the currently loaded video. */
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, YTPlaybackQuality) {
    kYTPlaybackQualitySmall,
    kYTPlaybackQualityMedium,
    kYTPlaybackQualityLarge,
    kYTPlaybackQualityHD720,
    kYTPlaybackQualityHD1080,
    kYTPlaybackQualityHighRes,
    kYTPlaybackQualityAuto, /** Addition for YouTube Live Events. */
    kYTPlaybackQualityDefault,
    kYTPlaybackQualityUnknown /** This should never be returned. It is here for future proofing. */
};
```

Don't use `Auto`, that value is for Live Events playback only.